# Parse Server Cloud Code Node.js compatibility

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, parse-platform, server

I am trying to develop an ecommerce iOS application.

I was wondering if it is possible to create this using Parse Server + Stripe. I would need server-side code to create customers, charge customers, etc.

Could I get similar functions like this in my Cloud Code?

```
// Using Express (http://expressjs.com/)
app.get('/customer', function(request, response) {
  var customerId = '...'; // Load the Stripe Customer ID for your logged in user
  stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, function(err, customer) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(402).send('Error retrieving customer.');
    } else {
      response.json(customer);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Your iOS application would talk to your back end using an API - be it a RESTful API, or something adventurous like GraphQL. You can build that API in any language you want, but Node.js is definitely a great starting point. That said, if you're not familiar with Node, or JavaScript as a whole, then you're best to start and the beginning reading up on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stripe node.js module in your parse server.

First you'll need to install the module using

```
npm install stripe
```

or adding it to you package.js file

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "parse-server": "^2.2.19",
    "stripe": "^4.11.0",
...
```

Then, in your cloud/main.js file, you can write a function that your iOS app can call

```
Parse.Cloud.define("yourCloudFunctionName", function(request, response){
    // You can retreive the user info from your request.params
    var user = request.params.user;

    // Call your stripe package using your API key
    var stripe = require('stripe')(' your stripe API key ');

    var email = request.params.email;
    // Maybe you want to create a customer using the parse email?
    stripe.customers.create(
    { email: email },
      function(err, customer) {
      err; // null if no error occurred 
      customer; // the created customer object 
      // You'll need to return something to the iOS code...
      if(err) return err;
      else return customer;
  }
);
```

On the iOS side, you can call the function this way:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"yourCloudFunctionName"
         withParameters:@{@"parameterKey": @"parameterValue"}
         block:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
     // this is where you handle the results and change the UI.
  }
}];
```

You'll want to send some user info into @"parameterKey": @"parameterValue"

More info on the stripe node module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe).

I hope that helps.

Comment: So the reference from Stripe docs on node.js is actually JavaScript code meant to be on server-side? That's what I've understood after reading about node.js and JavaScript.

Comment: Yep.  You need the server side to perform the actual transaction or action.  So the server side can be node.js  or PHP, etc.  Node.js is the server side environment and the language is Javascript.